# Convolution-Deconvolution pair gives slightly different dimensionality

Tags: tensorflow, convolution, deconvolution

I am using a convolution layer followed by a deconvolution layer like so:

```
tf.nn.conv2d(num_outputs=1, kernel_size=[21, 11], stride=[2, 2], padding="SAME", rate=1)

tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(num_outputs=1, kernel_size=[21, 11], stride=[2, 2], padding="SAME")
```

My idea is to make the initial image smaller, then bring it to its original size with the deconvolution. I am actually using the tf.slim functions, but the arguments are the ones above.

When I look at the input and output, I have a small difference:

```
Input shape :  (16, 161, 511, 1)
Output shape:  (16, 162, 512, 1)
```

I think it could be due to my stride size or kernel size. I've tried multiple values but none seem to reproduce the original dimensions.

Comment: When blowing the image back up, you must use integer multiples, so you can't choose exactly what the output image size is.

Comment: The only way around this for me was to cut the output to the input size, not much lost but I was hoping for another way.

Answer (score 0):

A popular methodology is to pad the input image such that the output after the convolution and deconvolution would be of the same size as the padded input. Then crop the output to fit the original input without the padding.